# How to override member type as another type in doxygen

Tags: c++, interface, virtual, doxygen, member

As my code heavily relies on dependency injection, most functional class members are pure virtual. Because of that generated collaboration diagrams only display first level of relation to this pure virtual member.

Is there a way to mark certain class members to be displayed in doxygen as another class? In this case I'd like to mark some references to be treated as a reference to the class implementing this interface. Something like:

```
class MyModuleIf
{ 
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
class MyModule : public MyModuleIf
{
    void doSomething() override;

    YetAnotherModule &yam;
};

class SuperUser
{
    /// @brief My special module
    /// @type MyModule
    MyModuleIf &myModule;
};
```

Currently doxygen will only show `SuperUser<>--MyModuleIf`.
I'd like it to show me `SuperUser<>--MyModule<>--YetAnotherModule`.

The only use would be for interfaces with single implementation so another possible solution would be to globally mark that MyModuleIf should always be treated as MyModule. By design those modules are devirtualized by heavy optimizations and are there only for ease of testing. The ability to easily see relations would be quite beneficial even at the cost of accuracy.

Comment: One option that comes to my mind is using INPUT_FILTER that will replace references to those interfaces with real class names. As I stick to one pattern and code style, it will be trivial script to do but I'm not sure about side effects yet.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you post (in the question) the differences between the default settings file and the settings file you used (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Did you have a look at e.g. the `memberof` command of doxygen?